Is there a Donkeyskin variant that involves a tunneling magic bed?
Wikipedia reports that Griechische und Albanesische Märchen contains a Greek Donkeyskin variant that involves a burrowing bed.

In a Greek variant from Epeirus collected by Austrian consul Johann Georg von Hahn with the title Allerleirauh, a widowed king declares he wants to marry his own daughter, despite her protests. To delay him, the princess asks him to fashion her two dresses of gold and a bed that can furrow through the ground to reach any other place. The king gives her the requested items; she takes the dresses, some ducats for money, jumps on the bed and goes to another city. The city's prince, during a hunt, finds the princess, wrapped in furs, in the forest and takes her in as a goose herder. Some time later, this prince holds a grand ball, and the princess attends it with her dress of gold. She dazzles the prince, but escapes the ball back to her low station, and throws some ducats to delay the prince. He becomes interested in finding her, so he holds two more balls. After the third ball, the princess loses one of her shoes and the prince tries it on every maiden, but cannot find its owner. At last, the princess, still wearing her golden dress underneath the animal furs, goes to bring some water to the prince, and he recognizes her.

I can't read German especially with that typeface, so is such a story located that where Wikipedia says it is, in "pp. 151-154.", or anywhere else in that book? Which I can't figure out with that book being 710 pages long while also being split in two and resetting page count here?
Also, Wikipedia's page on Allerleirauh, a.k.a "All-Kinds-of-Fur / Thousand Furs" makes no mention of the burrowing bed.

You may be making the schoolboy error of assuming that Wikipedia is reliable.

@Chenmunka - True, true. I would confirm it myself, but I'm not German?

In the admittedly hard to read edition of Griechische und Albanesische Märchen you found on archive.org, the tale you are looking for is actually in pp. 191-193. However, a more readable word-for-word copy of that book can be found here. The passage involving the bed can then be translated to:

"If he has really told you that you may take me, then take me in God's name. But first have two suits of pure gold made for me and fill my pockets with ducats. Let a bed also be made for me, and a shaft ten fathoms deep into the earth."
When the king had procured all this, the maiden took the clothes, got into the bed, went down into the shaft, and said, "Earth, open thyself still further." And the earth opened; she went in, and came out again at another place, and remained there.

It seems that whoever wrote that Wikipedia paragraph took some liberties: it's not the bed that burrows, but it's the king's daughter who gets her father to dig a tunnel for her, and makes the earth open up for her to emerge somewhere else.

Thanks, and from Google Translate, the Earth-moving powers aren't even explained. heh. ... Lol that King and Bishop conversation.
